# Date comparison with if statements

Tags: splunk

I need to use an if statement to set the dates in `startDateFrom` and `startDateTo` if not specified in the `selectedStartDateFrom` and `selectedStartDateTo` variables.

I then want to use `startDateFrom` and `startDateTo` to filter for entries with `Experiment_Instance_Start_Date` between `startDateFrom` and `startDateTo`.

The date comparison works fine, it's only when I add the if statements that it stops working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
| eval compare=strptime(Experiment_Instance_Start_Date,"%m/%d/%Y") 
| where compare>=strptime(startDateFrom,"%m/%d/%Y")
| eval compare=strptime(startDateTo,"%m/%d/%Y")
| where compare>=strptime(Experiment_Instance_Start_Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
| eval startDateFrom=if("$selectedStartDateFrom$"="", "01/01/1970", "$selectedStartDateFrom$")
| eval startDateTo=if("$selectedStartDateTo$"="", "01/01/2100", "$selectedStartDateTo$")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `"$selectedStartDateFrom$"=""` is wrong, so I changed that to `len("$selectedStartDateFrom$")>0`. I also needed to move the `if` statements to before the date comparison for the `startDateFrom` and `startDateTo` to be available. Also start date of `01/01/1970` returns no results, so I changed it to a later date.

```
| eval startDateFrom=if(len("$selectedStartDateFrom$")>0, "$selectedStartDateFrom$", "01/01/2000")
| eval startDateTo=if(len("$selectedStartDateTo$")>0, "$selectedStartDateTo$", "01/01/2099")
| eval compare=strptime(Experiment_Instance_Start_Date,"%m/%d/%Y") 
| where compare>=strptime(startDateFrom,"%m/%d/%Y")
| eval compare=strptime(startDateTo,"%m/%d/%Y")
| where compare>=strptime(Experiment_Instance_Start_Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
```